# Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number While Using pyspark in Local Windows machine

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting this error while starting spark application in spark. I am using Anaconda(Spyder)IDE. I am totally frustrated while finding the solution but still did not got any success for this .Please Please help.Earlier I was able to start the spark with below code but this error is coming from last 2 days

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("SSKafka") \
        .getOrCreate()
```

I had tried several things like setting JAVA_HOME,SPARK_HOME,HADOOP_HOME environment variables,Uninstalling/ReInstalling different  Spark verions,Anaconda,Java different versions,restarting PC
Spark Version: 2.4.1
Machine- windows
Anaconda Spyder with Python 2.7 and 3.5 both tried

```
import os
import sys
#os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.4'
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master local[1] pyspark-shell"
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_271"
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "C:/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7"
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "C:/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7"

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars C:/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.1.jar pyspark-shell'
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars C:/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar pyspark-shell'

from ast import literal_eval

# initialize spark
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()

import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("SSKafka") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: quick solution - use spark in databricks community version .. it's free and you can explore cloud as well

Comment: @dsk  thanks .i will try in databricks

Comment: Finally changed the IDE from Spyder to Pycharm.I am not facing this issue there..:)